# Is there a standalone dot.exe in Windows

Tags: graphviz

I am now working on a project to utilize Graphviz component dot.exe to generate a png picture, I want to know if there is a standalone dot.exe or something alike that can is a standalone executable in Windows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I did not find one, but [pydot](https://code.google.com/p/pydot/) is a candidate for my use.

pydot is just a wrapper, Graphviz is still required.
`Requirements
pyparsing in order to load DOT files.
Graphviz to render the graphs.`